# Is it possible to generate user-defined signal using an android phone?

Tags: signal, communication, cellphone, wave, telecommunications

Is it possible to generate an electronic wave signal using an android phone? (Theorically)

For example by customizing the firmware can I produce some signals like \$ f(t)=2 \sin 3.2×10^9t+3\cos 5×10^9t \$, where its units are \$W/m^2\$(Watt per metric meters), and \$s\$(seconds)?

Comment: Looks like you want to generate frequencies in the audio range (320t =51Hz, 50000t= 8kHz.) So, yeah you could generate them.  You won't get the amplitude, though.  [With something like this.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keuwl.functiongenerator&hl=en)

Comment: @JRE Thanks for the good material, but what I am curious now is about electromagnetic wave signal.

Comment: Outside of that, you aren't going to be able to do much with the transmitter.  It isn't intended to be used to generate arbitrary signals, and isn't really exposed (to user code or firmware) in such a way that you can set it to transmit  a continuous signal on a given frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically it may be possible to do something like this, but you'd need a lot of proprietary information from the manufacturer.

The part of the system that controls what gets output on the radio is known as the *baseband processor*; it's not usually accessible to the user at all. The radio is limited to a fixed number of frequency bands. Between the DAC output of the baseband and the actual radio will be some sort of *modulator*, which further restricts the kind of signals you can transmit to those using the particular modulations required for that radio.

You might be able to find a way of putting it into "emissions test mode", which causes it to emit a full-power non-modulated signal on a particular band. You're only supposed to do this in sealed RF test chambers.

Comment: Well then, do you mean that even the android OS is permitted to use only limited features of the baseband processor?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It appears as a modem to the operating system, running its own RTOS. A paper on reverse engineering the baseband: https://comsecuris.com/slides/recon2016-breaking_band.pdf (doesn't mention actual radio layer, that's even further buried)